# Proxy streaming in Stagefright does not work on some devices

Tags: android, audio-streaming, internet-radio, stagefright

I'm working on a mp3 streaming app and have used the NPR's `StreamProxy` class. For some devices which have SDK 8 (like EVO on Sprint) the native mediaplayer streaming of mp3 sounds really really bad. The same code works perfectly fine on HTC Incredible and all Samsung devices. Evo seems to have some problem when using the native mediaplayer to directly stream the mp3 audio.

When I tried to force proxy the **stagefright** player on my device (HTC Incredible) works perfectly fine but the EVO bails out.

What should I do to overcome this and force a proxy? Or how do I fix the bad mediaplayer playback in devices like EVO?